# Get a list of keys returned from PFObject Javascript

Tags: parse-platform, pfobject

I'm working on some cloud code right now where I have an id I query against which returns all the data for that row.

I then need to iterate over all the fields (columns) of data and make some changes to the values then update that row.

Im able to get the data from parse but im not sure how to pull out the PFObject keys to iterate over the data in a for loop , make changes then save.

Here is some sample code where I hardcoded a field value in but I'm not sure how to get the fields, then iterate over them in a for loop..

Also excuse the JS code, I its been years since I wrote any JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

var LocationTag = Parse.Object.extend("LocationTags");
var query = new Parse.Query(LocationTag);
query.equalTo("SomeId", "302d87f2-0188-4cbe-bc2c-e6dcbf822539");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var object = results[i];
      var data = object.get('T0fYiV9PeeU');   <--- hardcoded field key.. i need to iterate over all fields returned from the row.. 
      count = data.length;
      for (var c = 0; c < count; c++) {
        var res = Number(data[c].split(":")[0]);
        text += "Value: " + res + "<br>";
        sum += parseInt(res);
      }
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = text + ' sum: ' + sum + ' average: ' + sum/100 + results
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Any ideas.. sorry again if its just a simple JS issue.. but I need to iterate over all fields, returned in the PFObject

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of properties from a Parse.Object. The easiest way to to this is to call .toJSON() on the Parse.Object and then extract the keys from the json.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

    var pfObject = results[i];
    var jsonObject = pfObject.toJSON();
    var pfKeys = [];

    for(var key in pfKeys){
      if(jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          pfKeys.push(key);
      }
    }
    //Now we have a list of the pfObject keys in pfKeys
}
```